# OpenGL: force driver to keep VBO in video memory

Tags: opengl, driver, nvidia, vbo

I am specifying a large VBO and corresponding Index Buffer both with GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW. In each frame I make changes to a small subset of vertices and indices (different ones in every frame, but only a few compared to total buffer size) by:

-calculating min and max indices of the changes for both buffers

-mapping these min-max ranges with glMapBufferRange with GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_FLUSH_EXPLICIT_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONICED_BIT specified

-writing the changes to a few subregions of the mapped ranges

-calling glFushMappedBufferRange for each subregion that got changed

-calling glUnmapBuffer

-rendering

My problem is that the driver is (correctly) allocating the buffer on the VIDEO memory initially, but then when I map the buffer it is reallocating the (entire) buffer on SYSTEM HEAP and freeing the one on VIDEO and from then on renders the buffer directly from system memory (i see this through glDebugMessageCallback). This becomes the bottleneck in my rendering (PCIe is fast, but rendering the same buffer directly from video memory is about twice as fast).

Is there a way to force the driver to keep the buffer on video memory and only map the requested ranges into host memory and flush the indicated subregions back to device memory?
I'm on windows and on a NVIDIA card

Comment: You could modify the buffer data directly in the video memory with glBufferSubData(...). This function allows you to change a subset of a buffer(or the whole buffer)

Comment: BufferSubData won't make a change about where the driver keeps the vbo data and is actually slower than buffer mapping since it requires an additional data copy

Comment: @user1282931: You always need an additional data copy. Even if you map a VBO into your process address space you'll likely end up with an additional copy. Writing directly into PCI address space using synchronous commands causes all kinds of trouble (essentially it forces the CPU to sync with I/O operations). Using a command like `glBufferSubData` or `write` gives the OS and driver much more leeway in scheduling operations, thereby improving performance. Specific to Linux, but applicable to other OSs I recommend reading this: http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0004.0/0728.html

Comment: @datenwolf: it's correct that you always need a data copy, but glBufferSubData requires one more. With glBufferSubData, you first compute values into client allocated cpu memory, which then is passed to glBufferSubData which copies them over into driver allocated, pinned cpu memory (because otherwise synchronisation was necessary) and then DMA transfers it to the GPU. With glMapBufferRange you can compute the values directly into the driver allocated pinned cpu memory. glMapBufferRange does not do what you just described.